# "invalid request" "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" error trying to obtain oAuth2 access token with JWT

Tags: google-api, jwt, oauth-2.0

Per Google's [documentation on using service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests), this is what I did so far.

1. Created JWT (json web token) with following payload.

   ```
   {"iss":"XXXXXXXX.gserviceaccount.com",
   "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
   "iat":"1465531250",
   "exp":"1465534850",
   "scope":"email profile}
   ```
2. Using Postman, I did http post as follows in the hope of getting back the oAuth2 access token.

   URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

   Headers:

   ```
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
   assertion: <the JWT generated in step 1 above>
   ```

Instead, I got error response as follows.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Can someone find what is wrong with my request?

I have even tried a different endpoint of "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" with grant_type of "authorization_code" as well as "http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer". That too returned the same exact error!

Answer (score 0):

The `grant_type` and `assertion` parameters are not passed as request headers but as post request parameters (`grant_type=xxxxxx&assertion=yyyyy`)